# Broken python pipeline in Hadoop streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming, subprocess, pipeline

I have a large scale log processing problem that I have to run on a hadoop cluster. The task is to feed each line of the log into a executable "cmd" and check the result to decide whether to keep this line of log or not.

Since the "cmd" program opens a very large dictionary, I cannot afford to call the program for everyline of the log. I want to keep it running and feed the required input to it. My current solution use subprocess module of python and here is the code:

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def main():
    pp = Popen('./bqc/bqc/bqc_tool ./bqc/bqc/bqc_dict/ ./bqc/bqc/word_dict/ flag', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    for line in sys.stdin:
        lstr = line.strip().split('\t')
        if len(lstr) != 7:
            continue
        pp.stdin.write('%s\n' % lstr[5])
        pp.stdin.flush()
        out = pp.stdout.readline()
        lout = out.strip().split('\t')
        if len(lout) == 3 and lout[1] == '401':
            print line.strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above code works find when tested from my local machine. 
It is used as mapper when submitting the job to hadoop. I use no reducer and the following is the configuration.

```
hadoop streaming \
-input /path_to_input \
-output /path_to_output \
-mapper  "python/python2.7/bin/python27.sh ./mapper.py" \
-cacheArchive /path_to_python/python272.tar.gz#python \
-cacheArchive /path_to_cmd/bqc.tar.gz#bqc \
-file ./mapper.py \
-jobconf mapred.job.name="JobName" \
-jobconf mapred.job.priority=HIGH
```

The files in bqc.tar.gz looks like this:

```
bqc/
bqc/bqc_tool
bqc/bqc_dict/
bqc/word_dict/
```

In my opinion, the line "-cacheArchive /path_to_cmd/bqc.tar.gz#bqc \" should extract the tar file and extract them in a folder called bqc.

But it fails when submitted to a hadoop cluster with the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./mapper.py", line 19, in
        main()
      File "./mapper.py", line 11, in main
        pp.stdin.write('%s\n' % lstr[5])
    IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:335)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:590)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:18)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:194)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:335)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:590)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:18)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:194)
```

Anyone get an idea? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Zachary

Comment: why do you think `./cmd` is present? There are many problems with how you use Popen here

Comment: I agree with @J.F.Sebastian - are you certain that cmd is available in the current working directory at runtime? How are you submitting your job - Is the python code and this cmd program bundled into a zip file and then deployed using the -archives generic hadoop option?

Comment: @ChrisWhite - Thanks for the hint. The above code is used as mapper in the streaming job and I don't need a reducer. The mapper is cached by using the -file option. The who archive of the cmd executable and its required files are tared and distributed using -cacheArchive option. Let me edit and add the configuration I used.

Answer (score 2):

Mystery solved! It should be due to the memory limitation imposed by hadoop that caused the command cannot load successfully. The command needs about 2G memory and hadoop is configured to allow about 800MB per node.

Comment: can you provide a little bit more context (e.g. how are you expressing the 800MB, which config param?, how did you increase that to 2GB? did that actually solve your problem?)